# opencv-1.0.0 does not compile

Tags: opencv, makefile

I am trying to compile an old code (not written by me) which uses opencv-1.0.0.
I am using 64 bit Scientific Linux 6.
I downloaded opencv-1.0.0 from sourceforge.
Then,
./configure
make

Then I get an error as follows

```
cvcap_dc1394.cpp: In function 'int icvSetFeatureCAM_DC1394(CvCaptureCAM_DC1394*, int, int)':
cvcap_dc1394.cpp:796: error: overloaded function with no contextual type information
make[3]: *** [cvcap_dc1394.lo] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/ram/opencv/opencv-1.0.0/otherlibs/highgui'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/ram/opencv/opencv-1.0.0/otherlibs'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ram/opencv/opencv-1.0.0'
```

Any solutions? After googling a lot, I guess that my distro does not support IEEE1394 stack. Do I need to recompile my kernel? Any simpler way around this problem? I don't want to rewrite that code.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need the support for firewire, you could try to just disable it by using

```
./configure --without-1394libs
```

Does this solve your problem?

Comment: I am using firewire cameras for my project, so the openCV might compile but it won't solve the problem for me.